# Manipulating `body` element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Is it advisable to manipulate the parent of the DOM that is `body` element manually in React just like we do in vanilla JS?

Like is it good practice to do like this because here I am not manually manipulating DOM, but instead manipulating it parent element?

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is asking for opinions, which is specifically off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience: It's ok to do this.

Often this sort of thing is done when opening Modals (like [Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#live-demo))

It's a valid thing to do.